# Getting NoSuchWindowException when the child window is closed

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver

I have following scenario

I click a link(i.e. add comment link) in parent window to open a new window. I add a comment and click close button to switch back to parent window

After clicking on close button I am getting following exception

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'INLN50866593A', ip: '10.52.27.72', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

I have written following code to switch window to child window

```
public void switchWindow() {
        for (final String s : HtmlAutomationHelper.getWindowHandles())
            HtmlAutomationHelper.switchToWindow(s);
        SynchronizationHelper.pause(3000);
    }
```

After switching the window I add a comment click close button

But as soon as I click close button I get nosuchwindowexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible issue is you are closing parent window which you do not want to.

```
String originalWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
java.util.Set<java.lang.String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

for (String window: windowHandles) {

    //skip if parent window
    if(!window.equals(originalWindowHandle)){
        //if not parent switch to window
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        //do whatever and use close window here to
        //close the child window        
    }  
    // if you are done switch back to parent`   
    driver.switchTo().window(originalWindowHandle);     
}
```